# Encountered an issue where System::Threading::ThreadLocal<T> crashes MSVC 2010 & 2015

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, thread-local-storage

I was curious about the way Visual Studio handles dynamic initialisation of thread-local static variables, so I decided to test it in C++/CLI to compare with regular C++, using a pair of simple programs that should have roughly equivalent behavior (start three threads, each of which outputs five lines, then let them all finish before exiting gracefully; not concerned with scheduling, as long as `thr_internal()` is executed 5 times by each thread).

The C++ program worked just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int _i() { return 0; }

void thr_internal() {
    thread_local int i = _i();

    std::cout << "Call: " << i++ << std::endl;
}

void thr_func(int q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Thread: " << q << "; ";
        thr_internal();
    }
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(thr_func, 1), t2(thr_func, 2), t3(thr_func, 3);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Thread: 1; Call: 0
Thread: 1; Call: 1
Thread: 1; Call: 2
Thread: 1; Call: 3
Thread: 1; Call: 4
Thread: 2; Call: 0
Thread: 2; Call: 1
Thread: 2; Call: 2
Thread: 2; Call: 3
Thread: 2; Call: 4
Thread: 3; Call: 0
Thread: 3; Call: 1
Thread: 3; Call: 2
Thread: 3; Call: 3
Thread: 3; Call: 4
```

However, if I rewrite the program for C++/CLI, intending to get roughly equivalent code that uses `System::Threading::ThreadLocal<T>`...

```
#include <iostream>
#using <mscorlib.dll>

int _i() { return 0; }

void thr_internal() {
    using namespace System::Threading;

    ThreadLocal<int>^ i = gcnew ThreadLocal<int>(_i());

    std::cout << "Call: " << (i->Value)++ << std::endl;
}

void thr_func(System::Object^ q) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Thread: " << safe_cast<int>(q) << "; ";
        thr_internal();
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace System::Threading;

    Thread^ t1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(&thr_func));
    Thread^ t2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(&thr_func));
    Thread^ t3 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(&thr_func));

    t1->Start(1);
    t2->Start(2);
    t3->Start(3);

    t1->Join();
    t2->Join();
    t3->Join();
}
```

The compiler has an aneurysm while trying to process line #9 (the one with the `System::Threading::ThreadLocal<T>`).  I tried it with MSVC 2010 (installed on this computer) and MSVC 2015 (via Rextester), and both had issues:

VS 2010:

```
tls_cli.cpp
tls_cli.cpp(9) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
        This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal::TLSHolder ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
        tls_cli.cpp(9) : see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal<T>' being compiled
        tls_cli.cpp(9) : see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
        This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal::HolderBase ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Internal Compiler Error in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe.  You will be prompted to send an error report to Microsoft later.
```

VS 2015:

```
source_file.cpp(9): error C3252: 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal::FinalizationHelper::Finalize': cannot reduce accessibility of a virtual method in a managed type
source_file.cpp(9): note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal::FinalizationHelper ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
source_file.cpp(9): note: see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal<T>' being compiled
source_file.cpp(9): note: see reference to class generic instantiation 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal<int>' being compiled
source_file.cpp(9): note: This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'System::Threading::ThreadLocal::LinkedSlotVolatile ' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

I'm not very familiar with C++/CLI, so I suspect I inadvertently attempted to use `ThreadLocal` in the worst way possible and somehow broke its internal workings by accident, but I can't figure out any way to solve the error, and couldn't find any probable causes by searching online.

So... does anyone that's familiar with C++/CLI know what I did wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aneurysm is pretty descriptive, I suffered one as well trying to write an answer.   The ThreadLocal class constructor you are trying to use requires a delegate, not a T.  You need to get ahead by writing a ref class and make the ThreadLocal variable a member of that class.

Comment: @HansPassant Okay, I tried that, but it didn't work.  I'm not sure if I tried it properly, though, and I can't find any C++/CLI examples on the MSDN.  I tried making a wrapper class for the int, and tried putting the `ThreadLocal` inside a wrapper class; neither worked.  Whatever I try, I always get an error when I attempt to allocate the `ThreadLocal`, even if I don't pass any parameters and just use the default constructor.

Comment: If you have a working example of how to properly create a `ThreadLocal` instance, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried `ref struct ThrLoc { static System::Threading::ThreadLocal<int> i; };`, with and without the `static`, and had the same problem; I then tried making it a handle to a `ThreadLocal<int>`, again with the same problem.  I also tried a few other things, all of which caused the same problem.

Comment: I also hit this with Visual Studio 2013 when porting some C# code to C++/CLI. I haven't found a solution yet so I'll probably just disable this feature.